# Excel VBA Loop through column and colour cells that are not part of another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to write Excel VBA code that will loop through the data in a column and check to see if the values are present in a column on another worksheet.
I am doing this to validate that the data entered is from a value list.
If the data is not present in the value list I want to set the background colour of the cell to red.
The data is not entered into Excel so using a data validation list is not an option.
Some values may be blank in the column that I am validating which is fine but I want to make sure it checks all rows where there is a value.

This is what I have cobbled together so far but it is changing the colour in the top row instead of going down column I.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long


Set Rng = Worksheets("Lookups").Range("AC2:AC" & Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("COMPANY")

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("I" & i).Value, Rng, 0)) Then
            .Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use conditional formatting?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad. This is part of something bigger that I was trying to do but perhaps I can just leave this part out of it and use conditional formatting... thanks for the suggestion

Comment: (1) What have you done to try to debug this? (2) Why do you use ``.Range("I" & i).Value`` to look at the value but `.Cells(i)` to set the color?

Comment: @Gac_100, what I've realized that you are comparing two columns between Sheets for common values and try to apply BG color if No match/value,, and I'm sure you want to highlight Source Sheet's cells!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This VBA (Macro) code will help you to Highlight all Rows is Sheet1 if corresponding values are not in sheet2.**

```
Sub CompareSheets()


Dim i As Long, f As Variant

With Worksheets(1)
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        f = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value2, Worksheets(2).Columns("A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(f) Then
            .Cells(i, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- The used Column is `A form Row 1 onwards`, you need to adjust reference as your need.
- `Sheet1` is the `Source` & `Sheet2` is `Target Sheet`.

Comment: Your code might work, however writing it from scratch is less help for the OP understand issue in the original code.

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, it's been tested, fully functional,, I've tried to show in simplest Form,, modify the original should be bit messy, basic points like `Aplication.Match`, use of `Sheets` & `Color method` are similar to OPs code,, and since OP is using VBA codes then it's simple to realize that OP can manage with the Code!!

Comment: ,,,**Cont,,** seems you have not tested the code !!

Comment: @RajeshS This worked! I just removed the Not from in front of IsError and it worked exactly as I needed. Thank you Rajesh!

Comment: @Gac_100, glad to help you ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: @Gac_100,, why you have rejected this as an Answer since was Voted as an answer earlier,,, do u have nay issue?

Comment: @RajeshS no issue, this was very helpful! Just an accidental click. I realized later that I needed it to be case sensitive but another user pointed out that I can use Filter to accomplish that. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Gac_100,, it's okay ,,, happy to help U,, pls keep asing ☺